# CSRF protection if form tag not present

Tags: security, csrf

We have a page with a bunch of radio input fields and a button. On click of the button, the     value of the radio selected is added in `window.location.href` using javascript.

Do we need to apply any CSRF protection here? There is no form tag as such. If yes, then how to apply?

**HTML -**

```html
<div>
    <div class="component-content">
    <div class="component-row">             
    <div class="listbox">
    <input type="radio" id="91820000" value="1" name="user-programs" class="listbox__input"           onclick="ProgramSelection.selectRadio()">
    <label for="1" class="listbox__input__label">
                            Program 1                               </label>
    <input type="radio" id="2" value="2" name="user-programs" class="listbox__input"   onclick="ProgramSelection.selectRadio()">
    <label for="2" class="listbox__input__label">
                           Program 2                                </label>
    <input type="radio" id="3" value="3" name="user-programs" class="listbox__input" onclick="ProgramSelection.selectRadio()">
    <label for="3" class="listbox__input__label">
                            Program 3 
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="4" value="4" name="user-programs" class="listbox__input"  onclick="ProgramSelection.selectRadio()" checked="checked">
    <label for="4" class="listbox__input__label">
                           Program 4                  </label>
    <input type="radio" id="5" value="5" name="user-programs" class="listbox__input" onclick="ProgramSelection.selectRadio()">
    <label for="5" class="listbox__input__label">
                         Program 5                             
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>   
    <button class="selection-button" type="button" onclick="ProgramSelection.submitSelection()">
                Select</button>
    </div>
</div>`
```

```js
//javascript
ProgramSelection.submitSelection = function() {
    var redirectPath = document.querySelector('#redirect-url');
    var account = document.querySelector('input[name="user-programs"]:checked');
 
    var redirectUrl = redirectPath.value + "/login?program_id=" + account.value;
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to apply any CSRF protection here?

That depends.

What would happen if a malicious site provided a link to the same URL that a user clicked on?

- Does it **do** something? (as opposed to just retrieving information)

  - Make a bank transaction
  - Publish a comment on a website
  - Trigger an IoT device to turn on a light
  - etc
- Does it use the credentials of the user to ensure that only people who are allowed to do that thing do it?

If the answer to both question is "yes" then you absolutely need CSRF protection. (You should also change it to a POST request because GET requests as supposed to be [safe](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#name-safe-methods)).

> There is no form tag as such. If yes, then how to apply?

The same was as if you had a form.

Include a [token](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern) in the request. Just put it in the URL you are generating instead of using a hidden form field.